# Upload button will not fire programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

I have a button with which i want to use the "upclick"-plugin for uploading files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/upclick-min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="uploader" value="Upload" >

<script type="text/javascript">

   var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');

   upclick(
     {
      element: uploader,
      action: '/path_to/you_server_script.php', 
      onstart:
        function(filename)
        {
          alert('Start upload: '+filename);
        },
      oncomplete:
        function(response_data) 
        {
          alert(response_data);
        }
     });
```

Now the button works in itself and opens the "open file"-dialogue, but i cannot seem to fire the "click"-event on it programmatically. Ive tried all different ways of writing it syntax-wise:

```
if (ui.draggable.hasClass('ui-dragdrop-picElement')) {
                        //$("uploader").trigger("click");
                        //$("uploader").click();
                        //$('uploader').click();
                        //$('#uploader').click();
                        //$("#uploader").click(); 
                        //$("#uploader").trigger("click");  
                        //$('button#uploader').trigger('click');
                        $('#uploader').trigger('click'); 
                        alert("w00t");

                    }
```

and so on - any  idea why it  wont fire - i get the alert message!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("uploader")...
```

This isn't valid. There is no `<uploader>` element.

Your last `.click` uses the correct selector, but you'll want to use this with the `.trigger()` event:

```
$("#uploader").trigger("click");
```

You'll probably benefit a lot from going through the official jQuery tutorial: http://try.jquery.com.

Comment: This works fine. See this JSFiddle I've just whipped up: http://jsfiddle.net/M7NsQ/. If you click on "bb" the "aa" button click event will be fired. You should check your browser's JavaScript console to see if any JavaScript errors are being given, preventing your code from executing as desired.

Comment: neither this $('#uploader').trigger('click'); or this $('button#uploader').trigger('click'); triggers my button :( - i get no output in console

Comment: This probably means that your `if (ui.draggable.hasClass('ui-dragdrop-picElement')) { ... }` isn't being entered. Add an `alert()` (or ideally a `console.log()`) message to the start of that if statement and run your code again. If the message isn't displayed then that if statement's conditions aren't being met.

Comment: @user2214861 remove all those `$("uploader").trigger("click");` and `$("uploader").click();` lines from your if statement. You'll only need one `$('#uploader').trigger('click');` in there, followed by the `alert`, and nothing more. `if (...) { $('#uploader').trigger('click'); alert('...'); }`

Comment: i have the alert: alert("w00t"); at the end of the 'if' - and this is displayed as it should !

Comment: Does your button actually have a `click` event handler? What are you expecting to happen when it gets clicked?

Comment: you can see all the code i have for the button in the first code snippet in my question - when i click the button a "open file"-dialogue opens - and this is what i also want to happen in the 'if'-statement

Comment: Is your `upclick()` actually being entered? Can you not simply call `upclick()` directly instead of `$('#uploader').trigger('click');`?

Comment: if i just run upclick in the 'if' get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined upclick-min.js:1 upclick upclick-min.js:1 $.droppable.drop $.Widget._trigger $.widget._drop (anonymous function) (anonymous function) jQuery.extend.each $.ui.ddmanager.drop $.widget._mouseStop (anonymous function) $.widget._mouseUp (anonymous function) $.widget._mouseUp (anonymous function) _mouseUpDelegate jQuery.event.dispatch elemData.handle

Comment: I'd suggest looking through the documentation of "upclick" to find out how to properly call it.